# Removing grid lines in a CairoMakie plot by setting a custom theme

Tags: julia, julia-plots, makie.jl

I would like to set a custom theme for plots using CairoMakie to set `xgridvisible` and `ygridvisible` parameters to `false` for each of my plots.

I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
custom_theme = Theme(ygridvisible = false, xgridvisible = false )
set_theme!(custom_theme)
```

I do not want to run for every single plot and axes `ax.xgridvisible = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theming block objects like Axis requires using the (title-case capitalized) type name as a key in the theme. [This is explained in the documentation](https://docs.makie.org/stable/explanations/theming/#theming_block_objects).

For your specific case, making the x- and y-grids invisible is done like this:

```
using CairoMakie

custom_theme = Theme(
    Axis = (
        xgridvisible = false,
        ygridvisible = false,
    ),
)

function example_plot()
    f = Figure()
    for i in 1:2, j in 1:2
        lines(f[i, j], cumsum(randn(50)))
    end
    Label(f[0, :], "A simple example plot")
    Label(f[3, :], L"Random walks $x(t_n)$")
    f
end
```

Without the theme:

```
example_plot()
```

[image: four line plots with grey grid lines in the background of each]

With the theme applied:

```
with_theme(custom_theme) do
    example_plot()
end
```

[image: four line plots with no grey grid lines in the background of any of them]